# How to read InputStream only once using CustomReceiver

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have written custom receiver to receive the stream that is being generated by one of our application. The receiver starts the process gets the stream and then cals store. However, the receive method gets called multiple times, I have written proper loop break condition, but, could not do it. How to ensure it only reads once and does not read the already processed data.?

Here is my custom receiver code:

```
class MyReceiver() extends Receiver[String](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2) with Logging {

  def onStart() {
    new Thread("Splunk Receiver") {
       override def run() { receive() }
    }.start()
  }

  def onStop() {

  }

  private def receive() {


    try {

      /*  My Code to run a process and get the stream */

      val reader = new ResultsReader(job.getResults()); // ResultReader is reader for the appication
      var event:String = reader.getNextLine;

      while (!isStopped || event != null) {
        store(event);
        event = reader.getNextLine;
      }
      reader.close()

    } catch {
      case t: Throwable =>
        restart("Error receiving data", t)
    }
  }
}
```

Where did i go wrong.?

Problems
1) The job and stream reading happening after every 2 seconds and same data is piling up. So, for 60 line of data, i am getting 1800 or greater some times, in total.

Streaming Code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf
    conf.setAppName("str1");
    conf.setMaster("local[2]")
    conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Minutes(2));

    val customReceiverStream = ssc.receiverStream(new MyReceiver)

    println(" searching ");
    //if(customReceiverStream.count() > 0 ){

     customReceiverStream.foreachRDD(x => {println("=====>"+ x.count());x.count()});
    //}
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Note: I am trying this in my local cluster, and with master as local[2].

Comment: To avoid closing this question, you need to know that questions that fall under "Why this code isn't working" are considered off-topic

You need to go more on your debugging, such as, for 60 line of data you get 1800, do you have 30 nodes? does that mean all your nodes are reading the same data? what queue are you streaming from? what kinda logs are you getting, etc....

Comment: How are you managing your offsets?

Comment: I am not using any specific things. If that helps my problem, can you please suggest or provide some guidance, so that i can try.?

Comment: you need to manage your offsets, I.E., you are reading the first 60 messages, after that, your streaming job should know what messages did it read and process, in this case offset = 60 inclusive, the next time you read from 61 and greater.... etc..... How can you do that depends on what queue are you using or in general where are you reading from...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100494/discussion-between-srini-and-mamdouh-alramadan).